# Javascript: How to tell whether AJAX response is JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I've got an AJAX request that expects JSON in response.

But there's a possibility that what gets returns may not be JSON, but rather an HTML error page (unfortunately, with response type 200).

How can I tell whether the response is JSON or not?

(I'm using jQuery, if that helps.  But I can't use any plugins.)

Comment: Why is it returning error message like in that format? I think you should return something in JSON format with error provided and you can easily parse it later.

Comment: I have no control over what it returns.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Well, if you are using jQuery and you specify the `dataType` property of the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) call to `json` then jQuery will try to parse the JSON, and if it isn't JSON should call the `error()` callback.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/my/script.ext',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { /*YAYE!!*/ },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { /*AWWW... JSON parse error*/ }
});
```

---

**EDIT**

For anyone not using jQuery that lands here, the basic idea is to try and parse it as json and catch the error:

```
var data = 'some_data';

try {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
} catch(e) {
    //JSON parse error, this is not json (or JSON isn't in your browser)
}

//act here on the the parsed object in `data` (so it was json).
```

Comment: It seems like a big waste/weird to try to parse and then catch the json object when you could easily just check the `content-type` from the `xhr` object w/ something like `var ct = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type") || "";`

Comment: Because the content-type is unreliable. The only reliable way to check if an arbitrary string is json or not in JS is to try and parse it, and catch the error. Also, the content-type won't tell you if it is *valid* json.

Answer (score 17):

### jQuery auto-detects the dataType:

If the response is JSON, a properly behaving application would set the `Content-Type` to **application/json**.

So all you have to do, if the server is well-behaving, is to test if the Content-Type header in the response starts with application/json.

By chance, jQuery already does this by itself:

```
$.get('/foo', function(data, status, xhr, dataType) {
    if ('json' === dataType) {
        // Yay that's JSON !
        // Yay jQuery has already parsed `data` 
    }
});
```

jQuery detects the dataType and passes it as 4th parameter of the callback function. If the dataType is JSON, it parsed the JSON string and parses the resulting value as first parameter of the callback.

Comment: It is not working for me, it says dataType = undefined even thought in the page header I set `Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8`, may it be because I'm using `post` instead of `get`

Answer (score 5):

Seems like a good use of try catch:

```
try {
   $.parseJSON(input)
} catch(e) {
   // not valid JSON
}
```

Answer (score 4):

jQuery parseJSON function can be used for this. It will throw an exception then you can catch it go ahead.

```
data = '{}';
try {
    json = $.parseJSON(data);
} catch (e) {
    // not json
}
```

Comment: Very simple and yet clever. Perfect fit for my case.

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
    jQuery.parseJson(json_string_here);
} catch(e) {
   ... malformed json ...
}
```