# How can I tell whether the returned data of a successful $.ajax() is of html or json?

Tags: jquery

I have a form that gets submitted to the server via jQuery `.ajax()` POST. If the form passed the validation on the server-side, the server would return result in HTML for the client-end to update its presentation accordingly. If, however, the form failed the validation, the server would return result in JSON, which consists of the validation errors.

Both types of result would end up in the `success` handler of `.ajax()`. Since both types are possible, the handler needs a way to determine whether the result is HTML or JSON. How can I do that?

Note: On the surface, my question looks like the same as [this existing SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288136/javascript-how-to-tell-whether-ajax-response-is-json) but they are not the same. In that question, there's only one possible datatype (HTML **or** JSON), while my problem is about finding a way to deal with two possible datatypes (HTML **and** JSON).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For json data, `typeof(data)` will be `object`. For html data it will be `string`.

At least with data returned from ASP.NET MVC3 actions it works. I assume that it is the mime type that decides how jquery handles the returned data.

Comment: I already tested it with some basic Ajax calls, and it seems to work just fine. You beat me by 30 seconds on the answer though.

Answer (score 5):

If you leave the `dataType` parameter blank, jQuery will determine this based on the MIME type:

> dataTypeString
>
> Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)
>
> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response

ref: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: My problem is that I have two different code blocks to execute, depending on the datatype the returned data is in. The `success` handler has an `if` statement for figuring out which code block to execute, but I don't know what the `if` statement can use to check against.

Comment: jQuery will have already parsed it for you, so it'll be a valid Javascript object if it was JSON and a string if it's HTML.

Comment: @ahmoo: as Paystey says, you can use `typeof(response)` to check whether it is an `object` or a `string` that is returned...

Answer (score 2):

<s>If you are 100% certain that the data you are feeding your jQuery is clean of malicious XSS attacks then you might be able to use JavaScript's `eval()` method to your advantage.</s>

Thanks to [@SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) for [a suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) to swap out that nasty `eval()` I used.

You can use `$.parseJSON` to convert a raw string of text into a JSON object

```
function ajaxResponse(raw_data){
  try{
    // eval("var response="+raw_data); // try and avoid this if possible
    var response = $.parseJSON(raw_data);
    if (response){
      // We have a JSON inside the 'response' variable!
    }
  } catch(e){
    // We do not have a JSON.
    // Probably HTML content.
    // Might be a malformed JSON.
  }
}
```

As mentioned in the code, beware that if you pass a malformed JSON object then your callback will see this as HTML.

Note that the `dataType` specified by your `$.ajax()` call must be `text` so that jQuery doesn't attempt to parse it for you.

---

We all love alternatives that make our life a little bit easier - here is one for your situation.
Why not **always** return a JSON object? Something like this perhaps :

```
{"err":"","html":"<div>foobar<\/div>"}
```

And for an error :

```
{"err":"1","message":"You did not foo all of your bars yet!"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use typeof, it will report the typeof data your dealing with.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/8VWq8/)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use JSON to return the HTML as well?

What I usually do is set up my returned JSON object like this:

```
{
  //s=status, d=data
  "s":0, //0 means success, other numbers are for different errors
  "d":{ /* Other JSON object or string here */ }
}
```

So, in your case you'd do something like this (pseudo):

```
if (StuffIsValid()) {
    ResponseWrite('{"s":0,"d":"<html>html code here</html>"}');
} else {
    ResponseWrite('{"s":1,"d":{"errlist":["err1","err2"]}}');
}
```

Of course, you'd want to use the built-in JSON library for your server-side language of choice instead of using strings.

Then, in your jQuery `success` callback, I would do a check for the value of s.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'url',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        if (data) {
            //We have a JSON object
            if (data.s === 0) {
                //Success!
                //Do stuff with data.d as a string
            } else if (data.s === 1) {
                //Failed validation
                //Do stuff with data.d as an object
            } else {
                //How did this happen?
            }
        } else {
            //Uh oh, no object, user must have been logged out (or something)
        }
    });
```

This is particularly useful if the user has to be logged in to access the page you're posting to since you can catch the fact that the returned data wasn't a JSON object.