# How to detect JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, if-statement

Can I detect a JSON object and according to its object show a message?

I tried like this but it is not working :(

```html
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "example.php",
    data: form_data,
    success: function(data) {

      if(data.has("error")){
          alert('Invalid data')
      } else {
          alert('Correct data')  
      };

    }
});
```

If the data entered is wrong, ***data*** shows in the console something like this:

*{"object":"error","type":"wrong_number"*...

If this object contains error, I want to show error message. Otherwise, continue

Comment: You need `if (response.has('error'))`, not `data`. You're sending `data` to the server, and the server's response can be accessed using the first parameter of your `success` function. You also need quotes around `example.php`

Comment: My bad. The code should say `success: function(data) {` . Yeah, also, in real code there are quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to tell whether AJAX response is JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288136/javascript-how-to-tell-whether-ajax-response-is-json)

Comment: Just to make sure: you have a PHP server running, and `example.php` is an actual script that returns JSON?

Comment: Are you just looking to do `if(data.object === "error")`? That is, you want to detect a correctly-formed JSON response that *describes* an application-level error, right?

Comment: Maybe I’m blind - where is `response` defined in the OP code?

Comment: @Krease It was edited since then, it's now `data`.

Comment: @Krease OP replaced it with `data`

Comment: Ah, just noticed the edit

Comment: @ChrisG Yeah. The PHP app sends `data` back after verify the data entered

Comment: What does this question have to do with JSON?  Looks like just a javascript object to me.  Unless data is a string and you need to do `JSON.parse(data)` first?

Comment: @Rohalt what is `.has`? With jquery, `data` will be an array, an object, or a string. None of those things have a `has` method.

Comment: @KevinB If I can't use `.has` what should I use to detect `data` object? Btw everything is working fine, ignore any errors above `if(data.has...`

Comment: Just access it like you would any other object property. Don't forget to set your dataType to json.

Comment: @Rohalt could you do something like `if (data["object"] != null && data["object"] === "error")`

Comment: @KevinB Sorry. I'm kinda noob. How would you do this? And, yeah, in my real code `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: How do you access data when it isn't an error? An object is still just an object regardless of whether it's a success or a failure.

Comment: Tried this `success: function(data){ if (data["object"] != null && data["object"] === "error") { alert('Wrong data') } else { alert('Correct data') } },` wether data is ok or wrong, it shows "Correct data"

Comment: @Rohalt when you console logged `data` did it show it as a string or as an array?

Answer (score -1):

Be sure to set the dataType as 'json' on the ajax request so that the data will be parsed as json before being passed to the success handler.

```html
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "example.php",
    data: form_data,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {

      if(data.has("error")){
          alert('Invalid data')
      } else {
          alert('Correct data')  
      };

    }
});
```

Comment: While that's part of the problem, there's still the nonexistent `.has()` method.

Answer (score -2):

A json object is of type Object, since you will receive whatever, if typeof(jsonObj) == Object, you will not know if its a json object or just an object, but what you can do, is , read the headers in the request, and if its application/json, it will be a json object.

Another thing is, you can add a property in the json object like

```
  var obj = {
    customProp: 'Whatever property you want',
    data: {
    childData: childData
    }

}
```

I just understood your question correctly.

In a request theres a Success response, and an Error response

Success responses are response.status < 200 < 300 (generally they are 200)

what you can do, is, in the response of the function on your server, detect the object, if its correct just send the response, if it's not, send an error object

```
error = {errorText: 'Your form is not correct'}
```

Hope this helps!